App Store iOS App - Push Notification Delivery Issue showing status as Stored - Device Offline
We are experiencing issues with Push Notification delivery in our Live Application.
Upon reviewing the Push Notifications console, we have found that out of the 7.294M Priority Notifications sent in the last 4 weeks, only 1.226M were delivered to the device. The majority of the undelivered notifications, totalling 5.479M, are categorized as "Stored - Device Offline."

This issue is negatively impacting our customers, and we need assistance in resolving it to ensure smooth notification delivery.

